# How can I deploy my API on IBM Cloud developed in Python and swagger?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, ibm-cloud, swagger-ui

I'm developing an API for our back-end, using python 3 and swagger + connexion (I just followed this great tutorial https://realpython.com/flask-connexion-rest-api/#using-connexion-to-add-a-rest-api-endpoint).

I was succesfully created my own API, when I run it locally the swagger ui perfectly appears (using this http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/ui/).

My problem is when I deploy it on IBM Cloud when I'm trying to access it, i have this error: 404 Not Found: Requested route does not exist).

Please see below my sample application code, my default python file.

```
# Sample flask app to connect to our backend
# __author__ = 'paulcaballero'
from flask import Flask, render_template
import data_connection as dc
import os
import connexion
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api


APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

#Create the application instance
app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='./')

# Read the swagger.yml file to configure the endpoints
app.add_api('swagger.yml')


# If we're running in stand alone mode, run the application
port = os.getenv('PORT', '5000')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(port))
```

I want my default page to show all my endpoints.

Comment: If you have made no code changes then I suspect that `app.add_api('swagger.yml')` is not able to find the .yml file. You have `APP_ROOT` should you not be making use of that to locate 'swagger.yml'?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, locally It works in my machine, but when I deploy it on bluemix it cannot locate the swagger UI. By the way, I'm also using connexion.

Comment: This example might help: https://cloud.ibm.com/developer/appservice/starter-kits/6d62978c-a8a6-38fc-bac6-e3ee9c381e65/python-microservice-with-flask